# SimpleDateFormat parse in wrong date for 29 February

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have this wired

```
   public static boolean isFirstDayOfMonth(String format, String value) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return dayOfMonth == 1;
   }
```

Test and return true:

```
    boolean actual = CommonUtil.isFirstDayOfMonth("yyyy-MM-dd", "2021-02-29");
    assertTrue(actual);
```

The I found out SimpleDateFormat convert the date into 1st of March 2021, although there is not 29th in February in 2021. If I pass in 2021-02-30, which is invalid, but it return correct result.

Comment: I've not looked at your actually problem, but, I wouldn't be using `SimpleDateFormat` or any of the related `Date` classes any more and instead would be making using the `java.time` APIs instead

Comment: You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Call `sdf.setLenient(false);`

Comment: In addition to using java.time you should also respect the *single responsibility principle* better. Create one method for interpreting your string into a `LocalDate` and another for determining whether that `LocalDate` falls on the first of a month.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
java.time.LocalDate.parse( "2021-02-29" )
…
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )  // Thrown for invalid inputs
```

## *java.time*

You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

By default, the `java.time.LocalDate` class refuses to parse invalid inputs. Trap for the parse exception.

```
    try {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2021-02-29" ) ;
        System.out.println( ld ) ;
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        // … handle invalid input
        System.out.println( "Faulty input" ) ;
    }
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/oxmcXg).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).