# Turn auto count out of range month to next month

Tags: java, datetime-format

I am having trouble with DateTimeFormat with this kind of Date : `2021-07-32`
My formatter auto changed this into `2021-08-01`
How do i disable this feature and return an exception?

Comment: July 32nd is August 1st.

Comment: How can i disable this feature and return an exception?, that what i want.

Comment: Is that the Joda-Time `DateTimeFormat` class?

Comment: Or [`@DateTimeFormat`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html).

Comment: I can’t reproduce. I get `org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "2021-07-32": Value 32 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,31]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat parse in wrong date for 29 February \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042689/simpledateformat-parse-in-wrong-date-for-29-february)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ResolverStyle`, for example

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd")
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2021-07-32", dateFormatter);

System.out.println(date);
//Exception: Text '2021-07-32' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 32
```

Comment: Well, `LocalDate.parse(str)` will already reject this.