# Why is the expected exception not thrown on parsing invalid date?

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat, localdatetime

I get two strings and I must transform them into dates and show the difference in days between them. But I must throw an exception if one of the two dates is invalid.

This is the code I have so far for this task:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String d1 = sc.next();
        String d2 = sc.next();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        try {
            Date date1 = formatter.parse(d1);
            Date date2 = formatter.parse(d2);

            long dt = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) + 3600000;
            long days = (dt / 86400000L);

            System.out.println(days);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Data inválida");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But if I enter an invalid date like `02/29/2021`, it converts to `03/01/2021` instead of throwing the exception.

Comment: Try `formatter.setLenient(false);`

Comment: You shouldn't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, they're both obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead. In your case probably `LocalDate`. Then with `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2)` you got the time in between.

Comment: @shmosel it worked, thanks

Comment: @MCEmperor how i can change my formatter to use LocalDate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. This topic has been addressed many many times already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat parse in wrong date for 29 February \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042689/simpledateformat-parse-in-wrong-date-for-29-february). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905551/make-simpledateformat-parse-fail-on-invalid-dates-e-g-month-is-greater-than)?

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

> @MCEmperor how i can change my formatter to use LocalDate?

Like MCEmperor I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
public class Main {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ROOT)
                    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String d1 = sc.next();
        String d2 = sc.next();
        
        try {
            LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(d1, FORMATTER);
            LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(d2, FORMATTER);
            
            long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date2, date1);
            
            System.out.println(days);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println("Data inválida");
            dtpe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Example session:

```
03/02/2021
02/29/2021
Data inválida
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02/29/2021' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 29
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2017)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

You may also notice in the code how much more natural and simple it is to calculate the number of days between the two dates.

### What went wrong in your code?

> But if I enter an invalid date like `02/29/2021`, it converts to
> `03/01/2021` instead of throwing the exception.

That’s as designed. And I agree with you, it’s a confusing, surprising and unfortunate design. When you pass February 29 in a non-leap year to a `SimpleDateFormat` with default settings, it just takes it as the day after February 28, that is, March 1. It’s just one of very many reasons not to use that class.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Good suggestions! However, I would use `Scanner#nextLine` instead of `Scanner#next`. Though not required for this particular pattern, imagine the requirement changes to deal with patterns like `MM dd yyyy` or `EEE dd MMM` etc.

Comment: Yes, @ArvindKumarAvinash, me too. :-) In this case I took over uncritically from the question to make it easier to distinguish which changes would be *necessary* for migrating to java.time.